# Take mean of variables for linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mean

I am currently doing multiple linear regression analysis and was wondering if it would be legit to compute a new single variable by taking the mean out of four variables that are measuring the same construct and which all have the same scales (four questions were asked to assess a users disposition to trust technology)?

Would there be any issue with this approach, which would make the model less complex since I do have various other constructs containing various questions.

Comment: Why would you like to use the variables and their average in the same model? What would be the added value of the average for you?

Comment: How are the variables used in the model, i.e. dependent or independent variables? If independent variables, would you only keep the average and drop the original four from the model?

Comment: You may consider applying a factor analysis, which helps you determine a data-driven linear combination of your items.

Comment: @Firebug: Yes, it was my intention to only keep the average and drop the original four (all independent variables).

Comment: That is very important information, it's better to write that in the question body, otherwise the question is ambiguous (as can be seen in the comments and the accepted answer)

Comment: It is both confusing and unfair that the changes made to the question have rendered the answer irrelevant and largely incorrect.  So as not to ruin that answer, I have rolled back the question to its original version.  For answers to the new version, please start another thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that would not be legit.
Unless you're replacing that new variable with one of the other four.

One of the requirements for Linear Regression is for the features to be linearly independent. One feature being the arithmetic mean of other features => Features are linearly dependent.
If your features are linearly dependent, the data matrix isn't invertible and there is no single solution for the regression's coefficients.
Alternatively, the standard deviation for some coefficients is infinite, which basically means they can have any value.

If it's very important for you to try including that variable in your regression model, you can try Regularization methods - LASSO, Ridge, Elastic Map etc.

Comment: Changes to the original question have affected this answer. First, no form of regression requires linearly independent regressors.  Second, replacing four regressors by their average is identical to constraining their coefficients to be equal -- and one can imagine many reasons why that might be needed and legitimate.  Third, the statements about linear dependence and standard deviation are unrelated to the question because it doesn't contemplate adjoining the mean to the original variables: they would be "removed." Finally, regularization doesn't address the question, either.

Comment: First result from Google query "Linear regression requirements" says regressors need to be linearly independent. https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/statistics/regression-and-correlation/assumptions-of-regression-analysis.html.

Comment: That's a pity, because it's wrong.  Linear independence only assures that certain limited, elementary *formulas* can be applied.  It's a convenience, not an assumption. That page adds other superfluous assumptions that rarely hold, too, such as "all the variables are normally distributed;" and it contains bad advice, such as "outliers ... need to be removed."

Comment: I don't feel I can really argue with you, so I'll just say that: 1) I can find a dozen more pages saying that linear independence is a necessity, so is Normal distribution of errors. 2) If features are dependent one can easily show that coeffs could have any value, hence not necessarily make sense. I'm sure none of this is new to you.

Comment: It's not: you can find plenty about regression assumptions [here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+assumption+score%3A50)  You implicitly assume (1) (too narrowly) regression is solely for estimating coefficients (often it aims at *prediction*) and (2) (incorrectly) that linear dependence implies *all* coefficients "can have any value." The assumption of normal error distributions is often stated but is almost never satisfied in practice, so a more nuanced interpretation is needed (namely, that the distributions of the *parameter estimates* are *approximately* normal).

Comment: I get what you're trying to say: Linear dependency won't have any effect on the fitted values bc the dependent features' coeffs would cancel each other out. However, prediction wise, dependency can lead to an unstable model. If your coeff's value is at 10^10, any slight change in prediction data would distort your predictions. I didn't make any assumptions about all coeffs, only on those that are linked with dependent features.

Comment: Those are all good points.  But one example that comes to mind where that instability doesn't matter concerns compositional data (proportions of a whole), where all the regressors sum to a constant.

Comment: We also need to be careful interpreting what "linked with dependent features" might mean. For instance, consider $k$ regressors $X_j$ that sum to $1$ along with one more regressor $X_{k+1}$ orthogonal to all the others. Replace $X_{k+1}$ by $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{k+1},$ thereby "linking" it to all the other correlated regressors.  The coefficient of $X_{k+1}$ in any regression involving all $k+1$ regressors is not necessarily doubtful because of that.